# Get The max value row from a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 table in mysql callde 'Complaint' and 'Action'. I want to get the last action taken for each complaint. Tables are:

```
Complaint:
complaint_id    complaint_title
--------------------------------
1               Abc complanint
2               Xyz complaint
3               Dummy Complaint

Action:
ser_id    complaint_id    action_id    action_date
1         1               1            2018-09-05
2         1               2            2018-09-07
3         1               3            2018-09-10
4         2               1            2018-09-08
5         3               1            2018-09-15
6         3               2            2018-09-18
```

now I want to get the result like:

```
ser_id    complaint_id    action_id    action_date
3         1               3            2018-09-10
4         2               1            2018-09-08
6         3               2            2018-09-18
```

[DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/DcKnndn4ZhaiTsJJj5gBG/1)

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: maria db 10.1.34

Comment: The only thing missing is your best attempt so far

Answer (score 1):

use join and `group by` ,For your expected result below query is need,

```
    select complaint_id, 
   max(ser_id),
   max(action_id),
   max(action_date) 
   from Action a join Complaint c on a.complaint_id=c.complaint_id
  group by complaint_id
```

Or you can use in

```
SELECT a.*
    FROM Complaint c
    JOIN Action a ON a.complaint_id = c.complaint_id AND
        a.action_date in (SELECT MAX(action_date) 
                         FROM Action a1 
                         WHERE a1.complaint_id = c.complaint_id)
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/DcKnndn4ZhaiTsJJj5gBG/2

Comment: actually i have more columns on the Action table. I need all the column of the action table for the maximum 'action_id' row.

Comment: @TahmidurRahman you can you can use co-related subquery or  you can use sub-query

Comment: @TahmidurRahman https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/DcKnndn4ZhaiTsJJj5gBG/2

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you the results you want. It joins `Complaints` to `Actions` on `complaint_id` but also on the row having the `MAX(action_date)` for the `complaint_id`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Complaints c
JOIN Actions a ON a.complaint_id = c.complaint_id AND
    a.action_date = (SELECT MAX(action_date) 
                     FROM Actions a1 
                     WHERE a1.complaint_id = c.complaint_id)
```

Output:

```
ser_id  complaint_id    action_id   action_date
3       1               3           2018-09-10
4       2               1           2018-09-08
6       3               2           2018-09-18
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a48cdc/4)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select @rn := 1, @complaint_id_lag := 0;

select user_id, complaint_id, action_id, action_date from (
  select case when complaint_id = @complaint_id_lag then @rn := @rn + 1 else @rn := 1 end rn,
         @complaint_id_lag := complaint_id complaint_id,
         user_id, action_id, action_date
  from Action
  order by complaint_id, action_date desc
) a where rn = 1;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/DcKnndn4ZhaiTsJJj5gBG/0)